# How to dynamically pass arguments as varargs in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, permutation, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a program that will take an unknown number of arrays as input from the user and then print from them, the function that I wrote that print takes in varargs.

So what I'm trying to do is in my main method call `print(arr1, arr2, arr3...)` and dynamically change that so I don't have to set a restriction on how many arrays can be passed in.

My initial thought process was to store all the arrays in a 2d ArrayList and then unpack them, much like how JavaScript has the spread operator where you can have a 2d array and then do `print(...inputArrays)`, but it doesn't seem like Java allows this.

Comment: It's valid java code. What's the problem around 'java doesn't seem to allow this'?

Comment: You make a list of ArrayList and pass

Comment: When you say `arr1`, is that an array or an `ArrayList`?

Comment: When calling a method with variadic arguments, just use `getPermutations(inputList1, inputList2, inputListn)` or `getPermutations(inputListArray)`

Answer (score 2):

This method:

```
public void foo(String... args) {}
```

is effectively the same as:

```
public void foo(String[] args) {}
```

Really - check the bytecode, it's the same signature. Or try to make both of these methods in one class - the compiler won't let you, as they have the same signature. The one difference between `String...` and `String[]` is that any *callers* to `String...` get the syntax sugar of: Take all arguments passed in this position and create an array for them.

As a consequence, invoking a varargs method and passing in an array works fine:

```
public void foo(String... args) {
}

String[] a = new String[10];
foo(a); // compiles and runs fine.
```

The problem is that arrays in java are rather unwieldy, but varargs is based on them. You're on the right track to avoid them, but when trying to dynamically call varargsed methods you're forced into using them. To make matters worse, generics and arrays don't mix well either. Nevertheless:

```
getPermutations(inputArrayList.toArray(ArrayList[]::new));
```

should get you somewhere (this converts the arraylist into an array).